# Cannot associate accounts on careers.stackoverflow.com

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, linked-accounts

I keep getting an error saying "It's not you, it's us" when I try to associate my StackOverflow account on careers.stackoverflow.com

anyone else having this problem?

Update: I clicked the "associate account" button again just to get the full text of the error, and got this new error.

> Stack Overflow Careers cannot
>   associate your Stack Overflow account:
>
> because it is already associated.

but it's not.  My careers account still says I don't have a StackOverflow association.

---

**Fixed**

1. I logged out of careers.stackoverflow.com
2. cleared out my cookies
3. logged back in
4. associated my account

everything worked this time.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad you got it working - we pushed a fix for the exception you were getting (we DO get logs :)

I'm going to refactor the crap outta account association this weekend - too much Google OpenID cruft in there.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this happens when you have multiple accounts on the sites, like, say, multiple Stack Overflow accounts. Do you?

Edit: ah, I see it turned out to be an issue of making sure the right cookies were in the browser. Good to know..

Comment: No, I only have the one Stack Overflow account but I'm logged in to so, meta, and careers with the same openid.

Comment: @Your Edit - well, you could always just blame me anyways... stupid users :P

Answer (score 1):

It wouldn't accept my (delegated) Open ID to log in, but it associated my account just fine.

I can only imagine how many problems *that's* gonna cause on down the line...

Comment: note that some programmer checked in a minimum openid version of 2.0 initially, which is unlike all other trilogy sites. This has since been fixed.