# How can I change the OpenID associated with a SOC account?

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, openid

So I wandered on over to SOC, just to check the place out... Turns out, there's not much to see without logging in. So, I tried to log in. [And failed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24924/cannot-associate-accounts-on-careers-stackoverflow-com/24925#24925).

Seems the OpenID support was a tad broken initially. Slightly daunted, I grabbed a handy Google account and logged in with that. Entered a bunch of mostly-bogus information, clicked every button I could find, and finally, satisfied, wandered back here.

But I hate to just leave a bogus account laying around... Someone could trip over it and get hurt! So my first impulse is to delete it... But, I don't see an option for that. So maybe I could just associate my normal OpenID, and enter real data... But, I don't see an option for *that* either!

So, where's the control panel that lets me associate a new OpenID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing at the moment. Email us directly on this (but use the right email, eg, the one at the bottom of every careers page..)

Edit: there's an accounts tab now; you should be able to handle this the same way you do on the trilogy sites. The code is the same, even if the UI is a little different.

Comment: I forwarded an email I originally sent to your team@stackoverflow.com account. Whoopsie.